# Find last row of a specific range of columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that ranges from "A:EV".

I want to find the last row of only range "A:DD".

The columns might have blank cells, so I need to go through all and find the furthest row of columns A to DD.

How can I code it?

Comment: Same way you check for a single column.  Then generate a loop to go from column A to DD checking where the last row.  Store the maximum value.  [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) should give you a good starting point

Comment: @ScottCraner  Have a snickers, you are going blind, that is the same link I posted 8)  Better?.

Comment: I did not see the edit sorry.  On vacation and using my phone.

Comment: My problem is also that I get the last row of the table and not with actual data because the table has some blanks in the last rows and it is giving me wrong number.

Comment: Then use the FIND() method in the link provided by @ForwardEd .  It will find the last row with data not formatting.

Comment: @ForwardEd I got the reference.  Also it is my wife's family thing so I find solace in doing this.  When I can sneak away I get on my laptop for "work" other times I am sitting on my phone.

Comment: your answer is in the link provided by @ForwardEd.  Use the Range.Find() method.  It will do what you want.

Comment: I have tried "Find Last Row in a Column" and  "Find Last Row in a Sheet" from the link provided. I get error code with the first one and 8 with the second. Both not what I want.

Comment: @Scott Craner. For context: My table rows is 8 and the number I want for lastrow is 1, because I only have the headings and some formulas in row2 between DE:EV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

```
Sub foo()


With Sheets("Sheet9") 'Change to your sheet
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        lastrow = .Range("A:DD").Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row
    Else
        'Used 1000 to prove that it was not defaulting to this.
        'Change to 1 when using in actual code.
        lastrow = 1000 'Change to 1 when using. 
    End If
    MsgBox lastrow
End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Else lastrow= 1000? shouldn't that be 1 for an empty worksheet?  Assuming that is the only time you would fall into the else statment

Comment: @ForwardEd yes but I wanted to show that it was not defaulting to the else.  I will change it and put a note.

Answer (score 0):

And to adjust the range a bit, change the two column letters in these two lines.

This one searches over columns A:DD.

```
lastrow = .Range("A:DD").Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
```

This version narrows the search range to Y:DD

```
lastrow = .Range("Y:DD").Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("Y1"), _
```

Comment: And with a little voodo, if you are interested in also getting the column where the lastrow was found but don't want to exract it from .Address, use this.

Answer (score 0):

And with a little voodoo, if you are interested in also getting the column where the last row was found but don't want to extract it from .Address, use this.

```
sub voodoo()

    Dim theresult As Variant
    With Sheets("Sheet9") 'Change to your sheet
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            Set theresult = .Range("Y:DD").Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("Y1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False)
    Else
        'Used 1000 to prove that it was not defaulting to this.
        'Change to 1 when using in actual code.
        lastrow = 1000 'Change to 1 when using. 
    End If
    MsgBox ("LastRow " & theresult.Row & " column " & theresult.Column)
End With
End Sub
```